# Creating a custom method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to figure out a good way to go about this.

Lets say I have a table that has posts, with titles, and different status IDs.

In my controller index, I have:

```
@posts = Post.all
```

Then in my model I have:

```
def check_status(posts)
  posts.each do |post|
    # logic here
  end
end
```

So in my controller I have:

```
   @posts.check_status(@posts)
```

but I'm getting the following error when loading the index:

```
undefined method check_status for <ActiveRecord::Relation:>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It should be a class method, prefixed with `self.`:

```
def self.check_status(posts)
  posts.each do |post|
    # logic here
  end
end
```

Then you call it like this:

```
Post.check_status(@posts)
```

You could also do something like this:

```
def check_status
  # post status checking, e.g.:  
  self.status == 'published'
end
```

Then you could call it on individual `Post` instances like this:

```
@posts = Post.all
@post.each do |post|
  if post.check_status
    # do something
  end
end
```